# Counting Occurrences in MS Access

Tags: sql, ms-access, count, ms-access-2010

I am trying the return a list of all rooms that an **OCCUPANT** or **INVESTIGATOR** are associated with. I also want to only include people that are associated with more than 1 room.

I tried the following query

```
SELECT [OCCUPANT], [INVESTIGATOR], [ROOM NUMBER], [ROOM SUBUSE], COUNT([OCCUPANT]), COUNT([INVESTIGATOR])
    FROM [FACILITIES MANAGEMENT SCHEDULE]
        GROUP BY [OCCUPANT], [INVESTIGATOR], [ROOM NUMBER], [ROOM SUBUSE]
            HAVING (COUNT([OCCUPANT]) > 1 OR COUNT([INVESTIGATOR]) > 1);
```

Which returns a result like 
[image]

But with data like
[image]

Which seems to not include **Weibo Cai** or his occupancy in rooms 7148-*. Clearly this is because the count of him existing in that space is not greater than 1, but is there a way to reformat my query to obtain the data I want?

Thanks,
Otterman

Answer (score 0):

`GROUP BY` and `HAVING` are the right idea, but you need to just group by the *room* information.  Then use the `HAVING` to filter what you want:

```
SELECT [ROOM NUMBER], COUNT([OCCUPANT]), COUNT([INVESTIGATOR])
FROM [FACILITIES MANAGEMENT SCHEDULE]
GROUP BY [ROOM NUMBER]
HAVING (COUNT([OCCUPANT]) > 1 OR COUNT([INVESTIGATOR]) > 1);
```

I don't know if `[ROOM SUBUSE]` is of any interest.  This also assumes that `OCCUPANT` and `INVESTIGATOR` have `NULL` values (as opposed to blanks of some sort) when the fields are not used.

Comment: That seems to return a more correct list. Can I include the Occupant/Investigator name and Subuse without including them in the group by statement?

Comment: @Otterman . . . No.  You can put in something like `MAX(Occupant)`, it you wanted one not-so-arbitrary value.

Answer (score 0):

You could use 2 `where exists` to populate the right dataset like below:

```
`SELECT [OCCUPANT], [INVESTIGATOR], [ROOM NUMBER], [ROOM SUBUSE], COUNT([OCCUPANT]), COUNT([INVESTIGATOR])
FROM [FACILITIES MANAGEMENT SCHEDULE] Out
WHERE Exists (
              SELECT 'O' 
              FROM [FACILITIES MANAGEMENT SCHEDULE] ino 
              WHERE out.occupant=ino.occupant 
              GROUP BY inn.occupant 
              HAVING count(ino.occupant) >1)
or exists (
           SELECT 'I' 
           FROM [FACILITIES MANAGEMENT SCHEDULE] ini 
           WHERE out.investigator=ini.investigator 
           GROUP BY ini.investigator
           HAVING count(ini.investigator) >1)
GROUP BY [OCCUPANT], [INVESTIGATOR], [ROOM NUMBER], [ROOM SUBUSE];`
```